# Cheapest method for querying multiple columns with multiple values (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm looking at passing multiple values to a query to retrieve rows that only match exact matches of ALL values passed, matched within multiple columns.

For example, passing: "France", "Special" to this would return only the ID 3. If pass "France" only it would return both the ID 1 and 3. If I pass "France","Special","Sacred" it would return empty.

This is for illustrative purpose, real data could have more columns to interrogate, and also more terms passed to it.

```
+----------------+-------------+---------+--+
|      Name      |   Author    | Country |ID |
+----------------+-------------+---------+--+
| France         | M. Charmers | UK      | 1 |
| Worlds Apart   | D. Ramson   | Germany | 2 |
| Special        | R. Magee    | France  | 3 |
| Sacred Special | D. Monster  | Spain   | 4 |
+----------------+-------------+---------+--+
```

I'm querying quite a large database and am looking for the least expensive method for interrogating this data. Would be it be sensible to query using a collection of WHERE IN clauses or building subqueries?

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches here?

Comment: Yes, exact matches. I'll clear that up in the question above, thanks.